# Using sylow's theorem to show a group is non-simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

### problem

Prove any group G, such that |G|=48 is not simple.

### My solution:

$|G|=48=2^4*3=3*16$ so we can choose the prime number to be 2 or 3.

$n_2 | 3$ and $n_2 = 1 mod(2)$   **==>** $n_2=1$ or $n_2=3$

$n_3 | 16$ and $n_3 = 1 mod(3)$   **==>** $n_3=1$ or $n_3=4$  or $n_3=16$

I want to show that $n_2=1$ or $n_3=1$

so suppose that $n_2=3$ and $n_3=4$

elements in $syl_2(G)=3*15+1=46$

elements in $syl_3(G)=4*2+1=9$

but $46+9-1>48$  this is contradiction, so either $n_2=1$ or $n_3=1$

can anybody explain that if my solution is right or wrong? the part I am not sure about is

**elements in $syl_2(G)=3*15+1=46$,
elements in $syl_3(G)=4*2+1=9$**

Comment: This is not right. You have assumed that every pair of $2$-sylow subgroups intersects trivially, but this need not be the case (or at least you have not shown that it is the case).

Comment: because they are subgroups of G, so they all have the identity element, and they are conjugated, so they form partitions, is this what you suggested to be shown?

Comment: What do you mean by partitions? My point is that two Sylow subgroups don't necessarily have trivial intersection, so your count $3*15 + 1$ might be counting the same elements multiple times.

Comment: it is true that each of the 2-sylow group has 16 elements ? or it has just 2 elements?

Comment: Each has 16 elements. Check the definition of Sylow subgroup.

Comment: is there any way that you can tell if p-sylow subgroup intersect trivially

Comment: Well, if its order is prime then certainly this is true. Otherwise, not without doing some additional work. You can try to estimate the size of the intersection between them. For example in this case, if $P$ and $Q$ are distinct $2$-sylow subgroups, then $|PQ| = |P||Q|/|P \cap Q| = 256/|P \cap Q|$. Since $|PQ| \leq 48$, this means $|P \cap Q| \geq 256/48 \geq 5$, so $|P \cap Q|$ must be $8$ (and $|PQ| = 32$).

Comment: In fact, that leads us to another proof that $G$ is not simple. We have established that $P \cap Q$ has index $2$ in $P$ and in $Q$, so $P \cap Q \lhd P$ and $P \cap Q \lhd Q$. This means that the normalizer $N_G(P\cap Q)$ contains both $P$ and $Q$, so it also contains their product $PQ$. Therefore, $PQ \subseteq N_G(P \cap Q)$, which means that $|PQ| = 32 \leq |N_G(P \cap Q)|$, which forces $N_G(P\cap Q) = G$. But this means that $P \cap Q \lhd G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong, but it doesn't seem that a pure Sylow counting argument will crack this one, because we don't know how the $2$-sylow subgroups intersect. However, there is a technique which lets us exploit that intersection, as follows.

Let $H$ be one of the $2$-sylow subgroups. Then $G$ acts on $G/H$, the set of left cosets of $H$, by left multiplication. The kernel of this action consists of the elements $g \in G$ which act as the identity, meaning that $g(aH) = aH$ for every $a \in G$, or equivalently, $g \in aHa^{-1}$ for every $a$, or equivalently, $g \in \bigcap_{a \in G}aHa^{-1}$, which is called **core** of $H$. Let's call this core $K$ for brevity.

Since $K$ is the kernel of an action, it is a normal subgroup of $G$. If $G$ is simple, then $K$ must be either $1$ or $G$. It can't be $1$, because then the group action induces an injection from $G$ to $S_3$ (since $|G/H| = 3$). This is impossible because $|G| = 48$ whereas $|S_3| = 6$. So $K$ must be all of $G$. But this is also impossible since $K \leq H$.

We conclude that $G$ cannot be simple.

---

We can in fact say a bit more. Since $G/K$ must be isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_3$, which has order $6$, this means that $|G/K| = |G|/|K| \leq 6$ and so $|K| \geq |G|/6 = 8$. Since $|K|$ also divides $|H| = 16$, this means that $|K|$ is either $8$ or $16$. In the latter case, all of the conjugates of $H$ equal $K$, so $H$ is the unique (hence normal) $2$-sylow subgroup. So, if $n_3 > 1$, we conclude that $G$ has a normal subgroup $(K)$ of order $8$.

---

A further note about the core $K = \bigcap_{a \in G}aHa^{-1}$: recall that all of the Sylow subgroups of a given order are conjugate, so in fact $K$ is the intersection of all of the $2$-sylow subgroups. Since this is canonically defined, $K$ is in fact a characteristic subgroup of $G$, not merely normal. (We didn't need that fact here, which is why it is a side note.)